# CSS not working in Safari

Tags: css

Can someone let me know why the CSS class for my search input is not working in Safari? It works great in Chrome and ok in Firefox. It seems as though none of the CSS rules that have been set on the class 'sb-search-input' are being recognised by Safari.

Really can't figure it out!

Thanks...

URL: http://www.bboyrival.com/

CSS:

```
.sb-search {
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    right:80px;
    z-index:99998;
    margin-top:35px;
    width:0%;
    min-width:40px;
    height:40px;
    float:right;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: width 0.3s;
    transition: width 0.3s;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
}
.sb-search-input {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    border:none;
    border-radius:1px;
    outline:none;
    background:#fff;
    width:20%;
    height:40px;
    margin:0;
    z-index:10;
    padding: 15px 65px 15px 20px;
    font-family:inherit;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:200;
    color:#2c3e50;
}
.sb-search-input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #0F171C;
}

.sb-search-input:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #0F171C;
}

.sb-search-input::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #0F171C;
}

.sb-search-input:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #0F171C;
}
.sb-icon-search,
.sb-search-submit  {
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.sb-search-submit {
    background: #2d85a2; /* IE needs this */
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)"; /* IE 8 */
    filter: alpha(opacity=0); /* IE 5-7 */
    opacity: 0;
    color: transparent;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    z-index: -1;
}

.sb-icon-search {
    background-image:url(../images/searchicon.png);
    background-position:center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:contain;
    -webkit-background-size:contain;
    -moz-background-size:contain;
    -o-background-size:contain;
    z-index: 90;
    background-color:#2d85a2;
    -webkit-transition: all ease 1s;
    -moz-transition: all ease 1s;
    -o-transition: all ease 1s;
    -ms-transition: all ease 1s;
    transition: all ease 1s;
}
.sb-icon-search:hover {
    background-image:url(../images/searchiconhover.png);
}

.sb-icon-search:before {
    content: "";
}

/* Open state */
.sb-search.sb-search-open,
.no-js .sb-search {
    width:100%;
}

.sb-search.sb-search-open .sb-icon-search,
.no-js .sb-search .sb-icon-search {
    z-index: 11;
}

.sb-search.sb-search-open .sb-search-submit,
.no-js .sb-search .sb-search-submit {
    z-index: 90;
}
```

Markup :

```
<form>
      <input class="sb-search-input" placeholder="Search..." type="search" value="" name="search" id="search">
      <input class="sb-search-submit" type="submit" value="">
        <div class="sb-icon-search"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? Can you be more specific? What is the relevance of the jQuery you have referenced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Safari holds on to user agent styles for `<input type="search">` pretty hard.

add `-webkit-appearance: textfield;` to your `.sb-search-input{}` rules will do what you're after.

More information and possible style overrides here: http://priyanksharma.com/code-snippets/resetting-html5-search-input-in-webkit/